# Unable to sync Ropsten testnet with Geth 1.10.5

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

I upgrade geth to latest 1.10.5 stable, but my local ropsten node is higher than etherscan. This is the command.

```
geth --cache=4096 --maxpeers=50 --datadir=/data/eth --ethash.dagdir=/data/eth/ethash --http --http.addr=0.0.0.0 -http.api=web3,eth,net,personal --http.corsdomain=* --http.vhosts=* --ropsten.
```

Is there any problem with it? How should I do?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got it. It's a geth bug. A new release is published to fix it.
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.10.6